# A perfect domain that is not integrally closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Does there exist an integral domain $R$ of characteristic $p > 0$ that is perfect (i.e., $x \mapsto x^p$ is bijective on $R$) but not integrally closed in its field of fractions?

Comment: Tons of them. Let $R$ be a domain with integral closure $R'$ in its fraction field $K$ of characteristic $p$ such that ${\rm{Spec}}(R') \rightarrow {\rm{Spec}}(R)$ has a fiber with at least 2 points or a residue field extension not purely inseparable (i.e., $R'$ is not radiciel over $R$); easy to make such $R$. For the perfect closure $K_p$ of $K$, the ring $R_p$ of elements with a $p$-power in $R$ does the job (since $R_p$ is radiciel over $R$ and $R'_p$ is radiciel over $R_p$ with $R'_p$ normal and integral over $R_p$: if $R_p$ is normal then $R'_p=R_p$ and hence $R'$ is radiciel over $R$.

Comment: I should have mentioned that taking $R$ to be the coordinate ring of a nodal cubic gives something slightly simpler than the variant in the example below.

Comment: Very nice! I like this family of examples most so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S$ be the local ring of nodal curve, $R$ = inverse limit $Frob: S \to S$.  For example:

- $k$ a perfect field,
- $f(x,y)=y^{p+1}-x^{p+1}(1+x)$,
- $R=k[x^{1/p^{\infty}},y^{1/p^{\infty}}]/(f^{1/p^{\infty}})$.

Here's a complete local example:

- $k$ a perfect field,
- $f(x,y)=y^{p}-x^{p}y-x^{p+1}$,
- $R=k[[x^{1/p^{\infty}},y^{1/p^{\infty}}]]/(f^{1/p^{\infty}})$.

In each example $(y/x)$ is integral over $R$.

Comment: Though the formatting is actually pretty good, I think you should really TeX/MathJax this answer.

Comment: It appears to me that your ring is seminormal.  Is every perfect integral domain a seminormal ring?

Comment: @JasonStarr Let k=perfect field char p>3, R=k[[x^(1/2p^n),x^(1/3p^n):n>=0]]. Then a=x^(1/2), b=x^(1/3), a^2=b^3, but x^(1/6) isn't in R so R isn't seminormal.  R is another negative answer to the original question.  (Sorry for the primitive formatting.)

Comment: @DavidLampert — I did some reformatting for you. If you just add `$`-signs around your maths, everything suddenly looks a lot nicer (-;

Comment: @jmc Thank you. I'm a novice with formatting.

Comment: @DavidLampert I'm not sure that your $R$ from above is perfect, is it? To me it seems as though any perfect $R$ is seminormal by the following argument. Suppose that $x$ is in $Q(R)$ is such that $x^3$ and $x^2$ are in $R$. Then, writing $p=2r+3$ we have that $x^p=x^3\cdot (x^2)^r$ belongs to $R$. Since $R$ is perfect there exists some $y$ in $R$ such that $x^p=y^p$. But, then $(x-y)^p=0$ which as $Q(R)$ is reduced implies that $x=y$, so $x\in R$. So, $R$ is seminormal.